# RewriteCond having space

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying add a RewriteCond with HTTP header condition. 
It looks like as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Status Code} ^302$
```

I am getting syntax error because i have space inside RewriteCond. 
How can I escape this space ?

Comment: what do you want your .htaccess to do? Can we see the rest of this rule?

Comment: I am trying to make my server as Reverse proxy and fwd the response of upstream server to the client based on status code. Below is the rule   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Status Code} ^302$
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:Set-Cookie} ^.*$
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.abc.com$
       ProxyPass / http://xyz.abc.com/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://xyz.abc.com:12940/